# Fetch a Hibernate entity plus an additional field from the database

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a rather simple entity called `HUser` and I want to calculate distance from them to my user.

Perhaps, the correct way to do it is not to run the calculation in the database but in the code after I've received the data, but this question may arise once later in a different project, so I want to know how to do it sooner than later. :)

Here's the entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
})
public class HUser {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "lang", columnDefinition = "LANG")
    private SysLang lang;

    // ... Some other ~20 fields

    @Type(type = "string-array")
    @Column(name = "images", columnDefinition = "TEXT[]")
    private String[] imageIds;

    // The new field I've just added for storing additional data
    @Transient
    private Double distance; 
}
```

The problem is, this entity uses some non-trivial mappings to populate its' fields, so I'd prefer not to parse the DB response by hands. (It is `com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52`, by the way)

There's a repository with a new function:

```java
@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
@Qualifier(RO)
public interface ReadOnlyUserRepository extends Repository<HUser, UUID> {
    // ... Some other methods there

    // New function. Distance is in kilometers
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "" +
            "SELECT u.*,                                                 " +
            "    111.3199 * st_distance(                                 " +
            "    st_setsrid(st_point(u.longitude, u.latitude), 4326),    " +
            "    st_setsrid(st_point(our.longitude, our.latitude), 4326) " +
            "    )                                                       " +
            "    FROM \"user\" u, \"user\" our                           " +
            "    WHERE our.id=:user_id AND u.id IN (:ids)                " +
            "ORDER BY 111.3199 * st_distance(                            " +
            "    st_setsrid(st_point(u.longitude, u.latitude), 4326),    " +
            "    st_setsrid(st_point(our.longitude, our.latitude), 4326) " +
            "    )                                                       ")
    List<Object[]> getUsers(@Param("user_id") UUID userId, @Param("ids") Collection<UUID> ids);
}
```

The query itself is somewhat ugly, considering that `111.3199 * st_distance` repeating twice, and it returns `List<Object[]>` that I don't want to map to `HUser.java` manually.

I feel that having a Hibernate projection thing may do what I'm trying to do, but, to my knowledge, projections are used to reduce amount of fields selected from the DB, not to increase them. :/

➥ So, is there any way to fetch a Hibernate entity with some @ManyToOne relationships and non-standard column mappings together with some additional columns?

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of using sql `VIEW` and creating a subclass `HUserWithDistance` that would extend `HUser` with an additional field, and map `HUser` as a `@MappedSuperclass`, like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW user_with_distance AS
SELECT u.*,
        111.3199 * st_distance(
            st_setsrid(st_point(u.longitude, u.latitude), 4326),
            st_setsrid(st_point(our.longitude, our.latitude), 4326)
        ) AS distance
  FROM "user" u, "user" our
 WHERE our.id = :user_id AND u.id IN (:ids)
 ORDER BY 111.3199 * st_distance(
         st_setsrid(st_point(u.longitude, u.latitude), 4326),
         st_setsrid(st_point(our.longitude, our.latitude), 4326)
     );
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
})
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class HUser {
    // ... normal fields

    // Distance between this user and the user finding his matches.
    @Transient
    public Double getDistance() {
        return null;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table("user_with_distance")
public class HUserWithDistance extends HUser {
    @Column(name = "distance")
    private Double distance;

    @Override
    public Double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
}
```

But I don't think it is a good idea.